# filter movielist using javascript

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

https://jsfiddle.net/mf553ccL/

I want to choose the select the genre and then filter the movie list so only the movies with that genre is showed.

```
<body>
    <div id="select-parent">
        <select id="selection">
        </select>
    </div>
    <div id="output"></div>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
```

I have tried using:

```
if (selection.value == data.movie.categories) {
  classList.add('hidden');
}
```

But I am getting data.movie.categories.

> TypeError: data is undefined

This is my Javascript so you can see the code:

```
window.addEventListener("load", setup);

function setup() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', 'data/data.json', true);

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
            var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            var output = '';
            var genre = '<option> ' + "-- Select Genre --" + ' </option>';

            for (var i = 0; i < data.movies.length && data.categories.length; i++) {
                if (i < data.categories.length) {
                    genre += '<option> ' + data.categories[i] + ' </option>';
                }
                output += '<ul>' +
                    '<li> Title: ' + data.movies[i].title + '</li>' +
                    '<li> Category: ' + data.movies[i].categories + '</li>' +
                    '</ul>';
            }
            document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = output;
            document.getElementById('selection').innerHTML = genre;

        }
        console.log(data.movies.categories);
    }
    xhr.onerror = function() {
        console.log("req")
    }
    xhr.send();
}
```

My data object is in a JSON file:

```
{
    "movies": [{
        "title": "Mad Max",
        "categories": "action"
    }, {
        "title": "Willow",
        "categories": "action,fantasy"
    }, {
        "title": "Alien",
        "categories": "action,sci-fi"
    }, {
        "title": "Silence of the lambs",
        "categories": "thriller"
    }, {
        "title": "The Ring",
        "categories": "horror"
    }, {
        "title": "Gone with the wind",
        "categories": "drama"
    }, {
        "title": "Lion King",
        "categories": "animation, family"
    }, {
        "title": "Jumanji",
        "categories": "action,fantasy, family"
    }, {
        "title": "Heat",
        "categories": "action,thriller"
    }, {
        "title": "Blade runner",
        "categories": "action,sci-fi"
    }],
    "categories": ["action", "sci-fi", "drama", "thriller", "horror", "fantasy", "family", "animation"]
}
```

Comment: I can't find `data` in your question, too..

Comment: share you data object

Comment: it has now been implemented in the question

Comment: what line of code gives the error?

Comment: console.log(data.movies.categories);

Comment: i need to use the select value adn filter the movies according to the categories